# Parsing XML into Array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

So i have this XML structure:

```
<fields>
    <field name="agent_description" label="Agent Description" size="area" />
    <field name="agent_phone" label="Agent Phone" size="field" />
    <field name="agent_email" label="Agent EMail" size="field" />
    <field name="agent_listing_url" label="Agent Listing" size="field" />
    <field name="profile_video_title" label="Profile Video Title" size="field" />
    <field name="profile_video_sub_title" label="Profile Video Sub Title" size="field" />
    <field name="profile_video_url" label="Profile Video (YouTube)" size="field" />

</fields>
```

i would like to parse this into an array structure that looks like this:

```
array(
            array("name" => "agent_description", 
                "label" => "Agent Description",
                "size" => "area"),

            array("name" => "agent_phone", 
                "label" => "Agent Phone",
                "size" => "field"),

            array("name" => "agent_email", 
                "label" => "Agent EMail",
                "size" => "field"),

            array("name" => "agent_listing_url", 
                "label" => "Agent Listing",
                "size" => "field"),

            array("name" => "profile_video_title", 
                "label" => "Profile Video Title",
                "size" => "field"),

            array("name" => "profile_video_sub_title", 
                "label" => "Profile Video Sub Title",
                "size" => "field"),

            array("name" => "profile_video_url", 
                "label" => "Profile Video (YouTube)",
                "size" => "field"),
)
```

whats the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$fields = array();
foreach ($xml->field as $f) {
    $f = (array) $f->attributes();
    $fields[] = $f['@attributes'];
}
```

Comment: Not all servers have SimpleXML enabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$fields = $dom->getElementsByTagName('field');
$arr = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
  $arr[] = array(
    'name' => $field->getAttribute('name'),
    'label' => $field->getAttribute('label');
    'size' => $field->getAttribute('size'),
  );
}
```