# XML To PHP ARRAY with simple xml

Tags: php, xml, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing XML into Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428908/parsing-xml-into-array)

how convert my xml file to php array, this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<EKG_DS>
  <EKG_PASIEN>
    <DOKTER>1</DOKTER>
    <NO_RM>0007</NO_RM>
    <NAMA>DONI</NAMA>
    <UMUR>36</UMUR>
    <ALAMAT>JAKARTA</ALAMAT>
    <TANGGAL>28/01/2013</TANGGAL>
  </EKG_PASIEN>
  <EKG>
    <ID_IRAMA_DSR>2</ID_IRAMA_DSR>
    <DENYUT_JNTG>2</DENYUT_JNTG>
    <ID_REG_DENYUT_JNTG>2</ID_REG_DENYUT_JNTG>
    <ID_GLMBG_P>2</ID_GLMBG_P>
    <ID_BENTUK_GLMBG_P>2</ID_BENTUK_GLMBG_P>
    <ID_REG_GLMBG_P>1</ID_REG_GLMBG_P>
  </EKG>
</EKG_DS>
```

i try use this code but just string... i need an array..

```
if (file_exists('C:/download/171_EKG.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('C:/download/171_EKG.xml');
     print"<pre>";
    print_r($xml);
}
```

please help me...

Comment: You want the file as a string, or the data as an array?

Comment: i need data as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$xml2Array = array();
if (file_exists('C:/download/171_EKG.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('C:/download/171_EKG.xml');
    foreach( $xml->children() as $key => $value ) {
        $nodes = array();
        foreach( $value->children() as $k => $v ) {
            $nodes[ ( string ) $v->getName() ] = ( string ) $v;
        }

        $node = ( string ) $value->getName();
        $xml2Array[ $node ][] = $nodes;
    }
}
print_r($xml2Array);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the xpath command, it works great in creating an array.

For example, to create array of all Tags named: A

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("NameOfTheXMLFiles");
$arr=$xml->xpath("A");

Then fetch any alement with tag A as an array: $arr[0], $arr[1], etc..

Comment: could you tell me with full code... i am new in php.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code and it returned an perfect array of object, which is obvious.

Here is what I have tried

```
if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
    print_r($xml);
    $xml->EKG_PASIEN->ALAMAT; //Returns JAKARTA
}
```

In above code you can also find how to access a single record from objects array.